# set cookie on page load by session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

I´m conscious this might be a question that was asked already.

i need to set a cookie that expires in 6 hours on 1 certain page when user is logged in. example if user is logged in on home page show once a modal, display modal again after 6 hours even though if user logged out the page and logged in back he must not see the modal until 6 hours had passed.

I'm using gmt to have front end access to the site since i dont have access to the backend.

```
<script>

   $(document).ready( function () {
   doOnce()
 });


function doOnce() {
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*
  ([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
  var now = new Date(); //get the current date
 now.getHours(now.getHours() + 6); //add 6 hours to it
 $("#myModalcookie2").modal();
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
 }
}


</script>
```

is what i´ve got so far but is not morking on firefox and on chrome it simple keep popping up all the time.

I'm a novice with cookies and what i have is what i googled and customized